# USA Invitation Letter

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I was denied a US visa amonth ago . Can I use the same invitation letter and the supportive documents to reapply

Comment: Yes, but you'd want to make sure that the letter and documents contribute to your application. If not, they'd be of little use. And if they were an issue the last time, then no. While US visa refusals give few details, applicants are not required to provide an invitation nor are there any documents required for tourist/business visa applications.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you need to fix whatever problems caused your visa to be rejected. We don't know what they were.